# remove characters from filename in bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to remove specific characters from a file in `bash` but am not getting the desired result.

**bash**

```
for file in /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/test/*.vcf.gz; do
mv -- "$file" "${file%%/*_variants_}.vcf.gz"
done
```

**file name**

```
TSVC_variants_IonXpress_004.vcf.gz
```

**desired resuult**

```
IonXpress_004.vcf.gz
```

**current result** (extention in filename repeats)

```
TSVC_variants_IonXpress_004.vcf.gz.vcf.gz
```

I have tried to move the `*` to the end and to use `/_variants_/` and the same results.  Thank you :).

Comment: The code you posted could not possibly have trimmed the directory part from the full file name.

Comment: @chris : Is `TSVC_variants_` constant here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`${var%%*foo}` removes a string ending with `foo` from the end of the value of `var`. If there isn't a suffix which matches, nothing is removed. I'm guessing you want `${var##*foo}` to trim from the beginning, up through `foo`. You'll have to add the directory path back separately if you remove it, of course.

```
mv -- "$file" "/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/test/${file##*_variants_}"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 find . -type f -name "*.vcf.gz" -exec bash -c 'var="$1";mv $var ${var/TSVC_variants_/}' _ {} \;
```

may do the job for you .

Answer (score 1):

Simple way of doing this for a single file or if other files are named `TSVC_variants_*` in the same directory as the script or terminal.

Here is a simple one liner that will remove the `TSVC_variants_*` from all files with that listed in the front of the name.

```
rename 's/TSVC_variants_//;' *
```

output:
`IonXpress_004.vcf.gz`